# What is difference between android:enabled and android:focusable in android

Tags: android

If I use in the `EditText` that is as `xml`, the `android:enabled="false"` attribute, as the result I can not type in the `EditText`. Now, also If I use the `android:focusable="true"` attribute, So What are the benefits? While I use the `android:enabled="false"` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `android:enabled="false"` means that you can't change the value of that EditText (you can't change it by user interaction but can programmatically) but it's still focusable, so it can gain a focus as if it was any other focusable view.

`android:focusable="false"` means that the field can't gain focus so the user won't be able to interact with it but you won't be able to focus that field even programmatically.

Basically these 2 things are not meant for the same purpose, so I can't talk about benefits of one approach vs another, and you need to decide what is it that you want to achieve with your app and what its behavior should be and then use one of these 2 things.

Answer (score 0):

Enable is a state which tells you whether the EditText is active or not. Means user is allowed to interact with it or not.

When the EditText is active(enable=true), when user touch/click on EditText, it receives focus, the keypad will open up, once the keypad is close, the focus is brought out. By dault, view is not focused, when user tries to interact, it gets focused.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the property

```
android:enabled="false"
```

then your `EditText` is not visible else if you put the  `android:enabled="true"` then it will visible. By default its value is  `android:enabled="true"`

And if you use

```
android:focusable="true"
```

then your `EditText` is focusable means user can enter values in it.